# How to export org files to plain text files as it looks like in clean view?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, email, formatting

I want to print org files or share them with in emails.  Clean view looks good for these purposes.

Is it possible to export org files so that the output text file looks exactly like clean view (of course without theme colors)?

Comment: Have you tried org-export-as-ascii? It's not the same format, but perhaps is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @glucas, but if you try the two, you'll find that they are quite different.  I just want a pretty list but or-export-as-ascii tries to give you a text document.

Comment: @Ben By "clean view" do you mean [this](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clean-view.html)?

Comment: @erikstokes Yes.

Answer (score 3):

This gets pretty close I think although I haven't tested extensively:

```
# -*- org-ascii-headline-spacing:(0 . 0); org-ascii-bullets:((ascii 42) (latin1 167) (utf-8 8226)) -*-
#+OPTIONS: H:0 num:nil toc:nil @:t author:nil
#+TITLE:
* foo
** bar
** zim
*** gir
*** dib
```

Output:

```
* foo
  * bar
  * zim
    * gir
    * dib
```

If you do a UTF-8 export it'll use • instead of asterisk. If you prefer you can set those file-local variables on the first line as global using `M-x customize-group RET org-export-ascii RET`